# processing in iterations inside a MailboxProcessor, Seq.map vs Seq.iter

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

Today I had an issue implementing some simple processing inside an iteration in a MailboxProcessor.

At first I tried to do the iteration with Seq.map, but the code in the iteration was never called! Then I switched to using a Seq.iter for the iteration instead, and then the processing was done just fine...

```
type Agent<'Msg> = MailboxProcessor<'Msg>

...

let agent = 
    Agent.Start((fun agent -> 
                let rec loop = 
                    async { 
                        let! msg = agent.Receive()
                            match msg with
                            | SensorEvent(id, ts) -> 

                                ...

                                [for x in connections.[id] -> x]
                                |> Seq.map (fun light_id -> //Seq.iter works just fine here, Seq.map doesn't!
                                    let publish = new Publish<SimulatorBroker.SimLightOffMsg>()
                                    publish.Message <- new SimulatorBroker.SimLightOffMsg(light_id, recom_ts)
                                    peer.Publish(box publish :?> IPublish<_>)
                                )
                                |> ignore
                                return! loop
                        }
                    loop), tokenSource.Token)
```

**What I am puzzled about is why I couldn't use Seq.map?.. and now I am wondering if it get optimized away when it isn't assigned to anything?.. 
or if something else weird happens when you use Seq.map inside a Mailboxprocessor..?**

yes, I know Seq.iter is more appropriate for simple iterations that just return 'unit' anyways. But please forgive me, I am still learning ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seq.map` is lazy. It is not evaluated until you ask for the elements of the sequence. You can do a `Seq.toList` after the map and it will force it.
`Seq.iter` is strict, it goes through all the elements of the sequence.

Try in FSI

```
Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.map (fun x -> printfn "%A" x; x)
```

and

```
Seq.initInfinite id |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

So in your case if you want to force the execution and ignore the result, `Seq.iter` is more appropriate.

Comment: And this makes sense, because `Seq.map` is designed for inputs and outputs; why produce the results before you need them, especially if you never do?  Whereas `Seq.iter` takes a method returning unit, so it's all about side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The `Seq.map` operation returns a new sequence containing the results of applying the specified function to the elements of the input sequence. This means that you should only use it when you need to do something with the results. The reason why it is "not doing anything" is that sequences are evaluated lazily. This means that using `Seq.map`, your code just builds a sequence and doesn't do anything with it. (The fact that you have to explicitly ignore the result using `ignore` also suggests that there is something wrong).

The easiest way to write what you're doing is to use imperative `for` loop construct (which is the same what `Seq.iter` does):

```
 for light_id in connections.[id] do
   let publish = new Publish<SimulatorBroker.SimLightOffMsg>()
   publish.Message <- new SimulatorBroker.SimLightOffMsg(light_id, recom_ts)
   peer.Publish(box publish :?> IPublish<_>)
```